# SQL: filter a one-to-many query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a many-to-many relationship in my DB (but for my question it could as well be a one-to-many hence the title) that links files with tags. The users are able to search the files using the tags as filters.

For example:

`+ (a AND b) - c`

means the I want all files which are tagged with both the tag `a` and the tag `b`, but not those with the tag `c`.

In pseudocode, that would be something like:

```
getFiles(filter) {
  let matching_files = [];
  for file in files {
    let tags = file.tags;
    if filter.match(tags) { // something non-trivial
       matching_files.push(file);
    }
  }
  matching_files
}
```

I just realized that what I want to do is a search based not a number of individual rows, but on a group of rows, which is not really what SQL is meant for.

I've got an idea on how to implement this, which would be by generating dynamic intersect/except based on the search query. So the previous query would be something like:

```
(SELECT file_id from files, tags WHERE tags.id = a) INTERSECT 
(SELECT file_id from files, tags WHERE tags.id = b) /* <- this handles + (a AND b) */ EXCEPT 
(SELECT file_id from files, tags WHERE tags.id = c) -- this one handles the - c
```

So `+` groups would be a bunch of unions, `AND` keywords would generate `INTERSECT`s, `OR` could be a simple `OR` in the `WHERE` clause of there group, and `-` would be an `EXCEPT` on everything that's been filtered in before.

So my question is this, is there a simpler way to do all of that ? Because first this seems pretty hacky, and second this does not look efficient *at all* when the number of files grows up, as I would be querying over all files for *every group*. The solution does not have to be SQL (if there's some other kind of datastorage that would handle this better), but **please note I'm doing this for a desktop app** (so using something I can **embed with my program** would be nice). Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you miss a `JOIN` condition in your queries such as `tags.file_id = files.file_id`. You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to do the same job.

```
SELECT file_id 
FROM files 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tags 
   WHERE tags.file_id = files.file_id and tags.id = a 
) and EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tags 
   WHERE tags.file_id = files.file_id and tags.id = b 
) and NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tags 
   WHERE tags.file_id = files.file_id and tags.id = a 
)
```

If you have a filter like + (a OR b) - c then it can be expressed using the following sql

```
SELECT file_id 
FROM files 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tags 
   WHERE tags.file_id = files.file_id and tags.id IN (a, b) 
) and NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tags 
   WHERE tags.file_id = files.file_id and tags.id = a 
)
```

Efficiency is mainly related to the appropriate indexes. If you create index such as `tags(id, file_id)` then it should be fine (since you probably already have one on `file(file_id)`).

Comment: Thanks ! I feel stupid for asking this now that I see your solution ahah

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `intersect`, you can do:

```
select file_id
from file_tags
where file_tags.tag_id = a
intersect
select file_id
from file_tags
where file_tags.tag_id = b
intersect
select file_id
from file_tags
where file_tags.tag_id = c;
```

I would normally do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select file_id
from file_tags
where tag_id in (a, b, c)
having count(*) = 3;
```